# Change image on toggle div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have  [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/a2v5J/31/) which animates another div while changing the width of the main div. Now, I want to toggle the image. How can I do that? 
HTML:

```
      <button id="showmenu" type="button"><img id="icon" src="http://www.rizwanashraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/twitter-bird-v2.jpg" /> </button>         
     <div id="sidemenu" class="sidemenu">
       <div id="innermenu" class="innermenu">
         <div class="sidebarmenu">
               This should go left
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="table">
         content
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#showmenu').click(function() {
var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
    if(hidden){
    $('.sidemenu').animate({
        width: '200px'
    },500);
    $('.table').animate({
        width: '300px'
    },500)
} else {
    $('.sidemenu').animate({
        width: '0px'
    },500);
     $('.table').animate({
        width: '500px'
    },500)
}
$('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

});
});
```

CSS:

```
  .sidemenu {
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
}
#icon{
height:20px;
width:30px;
}
.innermenu {    
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background: #bcc1cb;
}

.sidebarmenu {
height: 100%;
}

.table{
height:500px;
width:300px;
background:pink;
float:left;
left:20px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: did you try changing SRC of #icon on every animate method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this where you want to change the image

```
$('#icon').attr('src', 'YOUR IMAGE.jpg');
```

That will change the SRC attribute of the image.

Example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/32/)

Comment: Updated the JSFiddle to toggle with the two images provided. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/32/)

Answer (score 1):

You could change the image src as per the example below, or if you want some more flexibility just toggle the css class and have the image details in the css.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#showmenu').click(function () {
    var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden'),
        icon = $(this).find("img#icon"),
        imageSrc = "http://www.rizwanashraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/twitter-bird-v2.jpg",
        imageAltSrc = "http://placekitten.com/32/32";

    if (hidden) {
        icon.attr("src", imageSrc);
        $('.sidemenu').animate({
            width: '200px'
        }, 500);
        $('.table').animate({
            width: '300px'
        }, 500)
    } else {
        icon.attr("src", imageAltSrc);
        $('.sidemenu').animate({
            width: '0px'
        }, 500);
        $('.table').animate({
            width: '500px'
        }, 500)
    }
    $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/a2v5J/33/

Answer (score 0):

Try $('#icon').src = the new image on the click event.

Comment: how do I make it toggle every time?

Comment: You would need to check if your sidebar was visible then change the image based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
top.$('.sidemenu').toggle(function() {
   $(this).animate({ 
 width: '200px'     
   }, 500);
```